# image upload?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, image, upload

i am having a mvc application.A web project and the language i am using is C#.

i am having a update category form and in that there is a file upload control please tell me how will i do the update functionality because in the update controller we usually pass the collections object.

please tell me what will I do..and How will I do.

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: This is a very poorly formulated question.  1. What language are you using? 2. Is this a web form or a desktop form? 3. What is a "collections object"?  And so on...

Comment: Please add much much much more detail to the question. What programming language are you using?

Comment: What language? What framework?

Answer (score 4):

Change the [enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM) of the form element to `multipart form-data`:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(
    "upload", 
    "controller", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}
)) %>
```

Add a file input to this form:

```
<input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" />
```

and read the file in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files["filetoupload"];
    // TODO: do something with the uploaded file
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller will have a **Request** property, which has a **Files** property.

```
foreach (string name in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[name];

    string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Somewhere", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
    file.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```